# Is it valid to have more than one await inside an ASP.NET controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I coded the following:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(Config))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get()
{
     var currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
     Config config = await db.Configs.FindAsync(currentUserId);
     if (config == null)
     {
         config = new Config();
         config.UserId = currentUserId;
         db.Configs.Add(config);
         await db.SaveChangesAsync();
         return Ok(config);
     }

     return Ok(config);
}
```

I have not seen this type of action coded before. Can someone clarify if it's okay to have two awaits inside of a method like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the correct way. The request thread from IIS will be released on both `await` calls while the DB is beeing queried and the execution will return afterwards.